# Two part, Removing last element and replacing two elements in node in Java

Tags: java, replace, linked-list, nodes

I'm working a linkedlist from my assignment, one part is to remove the last element from the list, the other part is to replace one element with a new one in the linked list.

I actually struggled to figure out how to put it together, I did some research on removing and replacing, and the result was not really helpful but there was one that is strongly related to replace.

```java
 public boolean replace(int element, int index) {
        Node cursor = first;
        Node prev = null;

        while (cursor != null && index >= 0) {
            index--;
            prev = cursor;
            cursor = cursor.next;
        }

        if (index > 0) return false;

        if (prev != null)
            prev.element = element;

        return true;
    }
```

but my assignment was specific about not using boolen, but using `public void replace(int oldVal, int newVal)`

the other part about replacing is like this

```java
/*********************************
// public void replace(int oldVal, int newVal)
// —replaces all occurrences of oldVal in the list with newVal.
//********************************

    public void replace(int oldVal, int newVal)
    {
          IntNode oldval = new IntNode(oldVal,front);
        IntNode newval = new IntNode(newVal,front);

        if (front == null)
        {
            front = newval;
        }
        else
            while (oldval.next != null)
            {
                oldval = oldval.next;
                oldval.next = newval;
            }

    }
```

Updated, still struggling if the code is correct to allow me to change one element with a new element in the linked list.

```java
 public IntNode(int val, IntNode next)
       {
           this.val = val;
           this.next = next;
       }
```

unless I am mistaken and that I dont need to use it.

the result shoudl be allowing me to remove a element from the end of the list, and to be able to replace a old value with a new one.

Comment: Could you show the code that calls removeLast() as well as how front and count are being defined?

Comment: sure
```java
  public static void dispatch(int choice)
    {
        int newVal;
        switch(choice)
        { 
....
  case 7: //remove the last element
                list.removeLast();
                break;

```

Comment: as for front and count being defined
```java
public class IntList
{
    private IntNode front; //first node in list
    private int count; //count all elements 

```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your node's .next is working correctly your removeLast should look something like this:

```
public void removeLast()
{
    if (front != null && front.next != null)
    {
        IntNode secondtolast = front;
        while (secondtolast.next.next != null)
        {
            secondtolast = secondtolast.next;
        }
        secondtolast.next = null;
    }
}
```

Based on the description of your replace() function, you are not going to be replacing nodes but rather the values of the nodes.

```
public void replace(int oldVal, int newVal)
{
    while (front.next != null)
    {
        if (front.val == oldVal)
        {
            front.val = newVal;
        }
        front = front.next;
    } 
}
```

Comment: so i need to make sure that both front and front.next is not null to ensure that I will look at the last element and remove it?

Comment: if front is null, there is nothing in the list.  if front.next is null then front is the first and the last in the list.  Depending on your specifications you may or may not want to remove front in this case.

Comment: I tested it and I understand now, thank you :D now I have one more part before I can turn it in :P I updated my code and I am not sure if it's correct

Comment: my code is almost very similar to that, I'm testing what I have and compare to what you recommeneded. but again thank you L:D